# Django Reverse Not Found When Unit-Testing

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am writing unit-tests for a Django app. The app works as expected. However, one of the new tests fails because the system is not able to find a reverse match for a view name. What am I missing?

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for
>   'video_uploader.list_videos' not found. 'video_uploader.list_videos'
>   is not a valid view function or pattern name.

**app/tests.py**

```
from django.test import TestCase
from .models import Video
from .views import *
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse

class VideoTest(TestCase):

    def create_video(self, name="Test Video", creation_date=timezone.now, videofile="/video/"):
        return Video.objects.create(name=name, videofile=videofile)

    def test_video_creation(self):
        video = self.create_video()
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(video, Video))
        self.assertEqual(video.__str__(), video.name + ": " + str(video.videofile))

    def test_videos_list_view(self):
        video = self.create_video()
        url = reverse("video_uploader.list_videos")
        response = self.client.get(url)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertIn(video.name, response.content)
```

**app/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'video_uploader'
urlpatterns = [
    path('upload', views.upload_video, name='upload_video'),
    path('', views.list_videos, name='list_videos'),
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Between the app name and the url name should be a `:` not a `.`. Try with:

```
url = reverse("video_uploader:list_videos")
```

Comment: Thanks! I think that was it. After I added the semicolon, this error has disappeared. However, a new one came. Namely, it is saying that it cannot resolve the `videos` URL, which is located at the project's `urls.py` and points at the app I am testing. Is there a special way I need to include the main file to make the tests pass?

Comment: Could you update the question with the ‘urls.py’ of the project and the error message?

Comment: I was able to move past the error. Thank you for your help!